# Neo4J Gem - Saving undeclared relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I am trying to create a realtionship between two nodes as described here
https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships 
`from_node.create_rel("FRIENDS", to_node)`

I am getting an undefined method for `create_rel`

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to create a Q+A system inside another model. So both Questions and Answers are treated as models right now.

I'm getting a `undefined method`create_rel' for #

event.rb

```
  has_many :out, :event_questions
```

event_question.rb

```
  has_one :in, :events
  has_many :out, :event_answers

  def create_questions_of(from_node,to_node)
    from_node.create_rel("questions_of", to_node)
  end
```

event_answer.rb

```
  has_one :in, :event_questions
```

event_questions_controller.rb

```
def new
    #is this needed
end

def create
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new(event_question_params)
    if @event_question.save
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        @event_question.update(admin: current_user.facebook_id)
        @event_question.create_questions_of(self,@event)
        redirect_to @event
    else
        redirect_to @event
    end
end

private

    def event_question_params
        params.require(:event_question).permit(:question)
    end
```

I have my new question sitting inside the event's index page since I wanted to list all the questions on the event after. I don't even need a `new` method in my controller right? I also don't really know how I would obtain the event that my question form is sitting on. Is that accessible through params?

**UPDATE**

Did you mean this

```
  def create_questions_of(to_node)
    self.create_rel("questions_of", to_node)
  end
```

and

```
 @event_question.create_questions_of(@event)
```

So I think I need to change my routes as well and nest questions inside to create
`events/123/questions/`

Then I can grab `events_id` and use `find`

**UPDATE #2**

events_controller.rb

```
def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new
end
```

event.rb

```
  has_many :out, :event_questions, type: 'questions_of'
```

event_question.rb

```
  has_one :in, :events, origin: :event_questions
```

events/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [:event, @event_question] do |f| %>

#form stuff

<% end %>
```

event_questions_controller.rb

```
def create
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new(event_question_params)
    if @event_question.save
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @event_question.update(admin: current_user.facebook_id)
        @event_question.events << @event
        redirect_to @event
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
    resources :event_questions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

Comment: That will work but I wouldn't do that. You shouldn't use `create_rel` unless you're working with nodes that don't have models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_rel` worked fine when I tested it just now. Is it saying `undefined method 'create_rel' for nil:NilClass`? If so, it means that your `from_node` variable doesn't actually have a node set. Make sure your objects are what you think they are.

The better question here: why do you want to do this? When you create an undeclared relationship, you have to write your own Cypher queries whenever you want to use it. If it's part of your code and you are using it regularly, it should probably have `has_many` associations in your models. `create_rel` really only exists to provide interoperability with nodes that don't have models.

As for your other question, you don't need a `new` action unless there's a route and a view that corresponds with it. If you're loading the form for a new question on your index page, that's fine. If your URL is something like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/events/123/questions/`, then you can get the Event ID in `params[:event_id]`. Run the `rake routes` command from your project's directory and it'll spit out lots of information that includes the parameter names.

Finally, when you use `self` in `@event_question.create_questions_of(self,@event)`, you're going to get the controller. If you want it to refer to the `@event_question`, just remove that first argument from `create_questions_of` and use `self` from within the method.

**Edit: Part 2**

You're getting the `undefined method` because `self` in `@event_question.create_questions_of(self,@event)` is the controller. You're trying to send @event_question to itself, I think. Don't do that, just call `self` from within `create_questions_of` and you'll get current EventQuestion.

You use ActiveRel if you want callbacks, validations, properties, etc,... If you just want a simple relationships, just setup the `has_many` associations in each model, omit `rel_class`, and either set them both to the same `type` or set `origin` on one.

```
class Event
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :in, :event_questions, type: 'questions_of'
end

class EventQuestion
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :out, :events, origin: :event_questions
end
```

`origin` says, "Look for this association in the reciprocal model and use the type it defines." It lets you not have to worry about synchronizing the type between associations.

After that, you can do `@event_question.events << @event` and it'll create a new relationship for you.

Comment: The undefined method is in EventQuestionsController. e.g. `undefined method `create_rel' for #<EventQuestionsController`. Perhaps I am not understanding the different ways you can create relationships in the gem. What I got from reading it was that you can make add neo4jactiverel to models to create a relationship if you think you need things like future validations callbacks etc. And the other way was this method. If that isn't the case, or I'm misunderstanding, what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: just to clarify what you mean on the last part, I made an edit above. if that's correct

Comment: Ok. I've made a third edit though I'm not totally understanding the routing part. I have a routing error as so `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"event_questions"` and ` missing required keys: [:event_id]`

Comment: I think you might want to close this question and start a new one for that, it's a general Rails question.

Comment: thanks. will try to post that tonight. I'll link back to it from here!

Comment: now my issue is with `undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass` . Because of `has_many :out, :events, origin: :event_questions` @event_question` should be able to call `events` method right? actually scratch that. I don't really understand why we have that in there. if `@event_question` already is one of my node objects

Comment: Definitely should be able to do `@event_question.events`. Try it from the Rails console, do `event_question = EventQuestion.first` and then `event_question.events.each` to make sure it's working the way you expect.

Comment: `event_question.events` does return something.. but it seems like it's the even_question object/node? would like to discuss a bit tomorrow if you're around. left you a msg on slack