# Neo4J gem associations and creating relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, associations, neo4j.rb

This goes back to my issue with this [Neo4J Gem - Saving undeclared relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860741/neo4j-gem-saving-undeclared-relationships)

In the documentation, they give an example of this

```
post.comments = [comment1, comment2]  # Removes all existing relationships
post.comments << comment3             # Creates new relationship
```

From what I understand, the first line would remove all relationships because it's manually setting all the associated comments to be comment1, comment2.

But what does line 2 do? `post.comments` should be retrieving the comments associated with post. Thus it seems to be creating a relationship with comment3 and the other comments. But don't we want to create a relationship between Posts and comments?

Either I'm not understanding the syntax and what it's doing or what is written isn't clear what is happening.

Looking at my example, we have

```
def create
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new(event_question_params)
    if @event_question.save
        event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @event_question.update(admin: current_user.facebook_id)
        @event_question.events << event
        redirect_to @event
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

If `event` is my event node and `@event_question` is my event_question node, why does `@event_question.events << event` create the relationship between my event_question and event?

Right now I'm getting an `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass` in my controller which is a another problem altogether.

My event.rb has

```
  has_many :in, :event_questions, type: 'questions_of'
```

and my event_question.rb has

```
  has_one :out, :events, origin: :event_questions
```

`@event_question` and `event` both exist but `@event_question.events` will return nil

Comment: This is a great question, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post.comments << comment3` creates an additional relationship between `post` and `comment3`. It doesn't do anything with the other relationships.

The reason this looks weird to you is because `post.comments` doesn't retrieve anything from the database. Call `class` on it or any `has_many` association and you'll see that it's a `Neo4j::ActiveNode::Query::QueryProxy` object, which you can think of as an unexecuted query. It doesn't actually go out and touch the database until you call an enumerable method like `first` or `each` OR a custom operator like `=` or `<<`. `<<` is defined in [query_proxy.rb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/lib/neo4j/active_node/query/query_proxy.rb#L171).

The lazy evaluation of QueryProxy objects is why you're able chain methods and do things like `post.comments.liked_by.username`. It waits until it's clear that you need something from the database before hitting it.

The reason you're getting `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass` is because `has_one` relationships work differently. They are not executed lazily because there's nothing to filter, there's nothing to chain, there's only one possible result. As soon as you call `@event_question.events`, it hits the database and since nothing is set, it returns `nil`. The error means what it says: `nil` does not have a `<<` method. Use `@event_question.events = event` and you'll be fine. You may want to change that association to `has_one :out, :event, origin: :event_questions` to avoid confusion in the future.